# Neo4j Create Duplicate Edges

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I'm currently creating a schedule data. It has base schedule and I want to be able to create a copy with all the edges.

When a copy is needed, it will create a new 'Schedule' node with properties, and the all the edges from the 'BaseSchedule' including their properties too and then create a 'Created_From' edge between the 'BaseSchedule' and 'Schedule'.

The numbers under each icon is their unique ID constraint and I'm using CypherClient in C#.

So far I can create the BaseSchedule and Locs

I have method that when the database is empty, it will add every *Location* and *BaseSchedule*

```
  graphClient.Cypher
        .Unwind(locs, "lcs")
        .Merge("(l:Loc {Id: lcs.Id})")
        .OnCreate()
        .Set("l = lcs")
        .ExecuteWithoutResults();

  graphClient.Cypher
        .Unwind(scheds, "sc")                
        .Merge("(s:BaseSchedule {Id: sc.Id})")
        .OnCreate()
        .Set("s = sc")               
        .ExecuteWithoutResults();

  //Flatten travels_via and add links.
  graphClient.Cypher
        .Unwind(links, "lnk")                
        .Match("(s:BaseSchedule {Id: lnk.BaseId})")
        .Match("(l:Loc {Id: lnk.LocationId})")
        .Create("(s)-[tv:Travels_Via]->(l)")            
        .Set("tv.Time = lnk.Time")               
        .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

When running the simulation and a schedule gets activated, I want to to create a *Schedule* and clone the edges that are associated with the *BaseSchedule*.

```
  graphClient.Cypher                        
        .Match("(bs:BaseSchedule {Id: 1234})")-[t:Travels_Via]->(l:Loc)
        //.Create a Schedule with same properties of BaseSchedule
        //.Create relationship between Schedule and BaseSchedule
        //.Get all Travels_Via from above match and create new relationships 
          with the same properties. I suspect a collect and unwind are 
          needed, but I've never used them together.
        .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

j

```
public class BaseSchedule
{
     public long Id {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}

     public List<Travels_Via> Locations {get;set;}
}

public class Schedule : BaseSchedule
{
    public bool Activated {get;set;}
}

public class Travels_Via{
    public long BaseId {get;set;}
    public long LocationId {get;set;}
    public DateTime Time {get;set;}
}

public class Location {

    public long Id {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}

}
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: Please share what you have done so far and what are the issues you are facing?

Comment: So far I have a base schedule linked to each location. I can easily create a Schedule but I have no idea how to get the original travels_via connected to the base schedule and create duplicates connected the the Schedule as well.

Comment: Hi Liam, I think Raj was more after some example C# code to show where you've got to - without that it's hard to see where to go.

Comment: I've added some code samples. I was using my mobile at the time but now got access to a PC.

Comment: You may want to look at [apoc.refactor.cloneNodesWithRelationships()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#graph-refactoring) from [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/). Seems that does exactly what you want here.

Comment: I'll give it a go, thanks.